# PDFBox : Converting to image : Quality loss when converting PDF containing scanned documents

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

My use case is pretty simple. I need to convert the PDFs to images.I tried using apache pdfbox and i am having some trouble in converting pdfs which contains scanned images. when i convert scanned image the image clarity is lost due to compression/scaling. So i was trying to extract the image data from the PDF and then store it. But the problem is i may get PDF files which will contain images and text  in which case i would need to fallback to image conversion mode. The problem is how to differentiate between the pages/documents having only image and the ones with composite data. I was thinking i could use ProcSet defenition for this purpose but looks like it is marked as obsolete and non-reliable according to PDF specifications. Other possibility is to check all the objects linked to that page and see if it contains anything other than images. Please let me know if there is an easier way of doing this 
Thanks

Comment: You could first try text extraction. If there is no text to be found, go for image extraction. If you get exactly one image per page, chances are that that's a scanned page. (unfortunately this ignores vector graphics)

Comment: @mkl Thanks. I guess thats what i will end up doing

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is convert pdf to image, It is better to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for that. If you use ImageMagick, there is a lot options to change the quality of the image. And converting pdf to image is pretty simple using ImageMagick.